# Laravel Nova Hide view button from HasMany field

Tags: laravel-nova, laravel-7

i need to hide view button on HasMany field

In my Manager resource i have new panel with HasMany Relationship Field

```
new Panel('Orders History', [
                HasMany::make('Orders')
            ]),
```

I was trying to use policies as described in docs: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/authorization.html#relationships

in my ManagerPolicy class i create method

```
    public function viewOrder($user)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

but its not working...
Need some ideas what im doing wrong

P.S. Please keep in mind that i need to hide view button only on relation the orders page should have this functionality